# Есть ли в Symfony2 (doctrine2) функция для определения статуса объекта?

Tags: doctrine2, объекты, symfony2

Которую можно записать в Entity класс и которая определяет, является ли объект только что созданным или нет.

Comment: а для чего?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насчет функции не скажу, но разве наличие уникального `id`, который сейчас присутствует во всех таблицах, не может являться таким опознавательным знаком?